# Jquery: set style part of text in input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, coding-style

I want to create some text based on user input, and when user enter some text, the first word will automatically set backgroundcolor, but the other words still remain same (no background color), can I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: You can set the color of the whole text inside the textbox. But a portion of it seems difficult.

Comment: ic, we've thinking to provide preview area, so when user type some text, it will previewed.

thx Phoenix.

Comment: i want simply method, so using WYSIWYG is not an option.

Comment: So why do you want to show a preview of the text entered in a textbox. Will the textbox accept html characters?

Answer (score 1):

WYSIWYG editor will be the best choice for previewing text and editing at the same time.

Some popular ones are

1. [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/index.php)
2. [STEditor](http://www.gosu.pl/STEditor/)
3. [FCKeditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with an iFrame if you turn designMode on, add an event listener for keypress then wrap the first word in the iFrames body with <span style='background-color: red'></span>. You would then have to have a hidden form field that mirrored the data that is typed into the iFrame (removing the span tag).

If you want to go this way let me know if you need any more help.